# Not to show keyboard when focusing a searchbox

Tags: c#, keyboard, hide, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app (in Xamarin.Forms) which will be used with an external barcode scanner, so **I don't need to show** the tactile **keyboard** each time I put the focus in an entry/searchbox/etc.

How can I do this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: I am trying with a custom renderer but I don't find the properties to modify for reach this behavior.

Comment: @thisOneGuy great comments, it could be a barcode "wireless scanner"? OP please elaborate? Ie https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/input/keyboards/dismiss_the_keyboard/

Comment: @thisOneGuy I don't understand your question. I need the search, but the end-user does not use the tactile keyboard because he is using an external barcode scanner. So I would like to hide the keyboard.

Comment: I need the search control for search between items in a list. I am grate if you help me but I don't understand your questions. What is it important here, to know why I am using this control or the question I am doing??

Comment: why dont you have one page for the scanner and one for the search ?

Comment: I need this feature, forget the rest... Thanks you.

Comment: @thisOneGuy so people see the number scanned in - a label might be better, but this doesn't answer my question with the Xamarin link to hide the keyboard?

Comment: @JeremyThompson that solution is not what I am looking for. I don't want to dismiss the keyboard, I want to hide it keeping the focus in the control.

Comment: What have you found to do this? What are you basing this off? Show all your research

Comment: If I'm understanding this right (1) you scan the barcode (2) you show that code in numeric format in an Entry (3) you want to give the option to search that code and that's why it is in an Entry and not a Label? If that's correct, I have another question: At what point is the keyboard showing? (between 1 and 2, at 2, etc)

Comment: @dsnunez a Label is not the correct approach. The scanner behavior is like a keyboard: it reads the barcode, places the code into the searchbox focused, and do submit. Trust me I have thought in all the approaches and this is the correct one.

I only need to know if it is possible to do it, but definitely a Label is no the solution.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26016/how-to-avoid-showing-keyboard-when-focusing-entrycell

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never want the keyboard to never show whatsoever on an `Entry`, you can set the Keyboard property to `null` in the Entry's constructor.

```
var scannerEntry = new Entry
{
    Keyboard = null,
    Placeholder = "Scan an item"
};
```

Because the Xamarin.Forms API does not expose a `Keyboard` property on the `SearchBar` class, you can write a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/). The iOS implementation can use `ResignFirstResponder` in the `OnElementChanged` override to prevent the keyboard from ever showing:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScannerSearchBar), typeof(ScannerSearchBardRenderer))]
namespace HideKeyboard.iOS
{
    public class ScannerSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                if (Focused)
                {
                    ResignFirstResponder();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems nice, I am going to try. Do you have idea about how I can do this in Android? Thanks.